# integrating a javascript sdk in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, sdk

I want to use a javascript sdk inside of my flutter app (the pi network sdk only supports javascript), I am building this app for pi network hackathone

I tried to do some thing like that but it didn't :

```
class Test2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: TextButton(
          child: Text("click"),
          onPressed: () {
            js.context.callMethod("eval", [
              """require(['https://sdk.minepi.com/pi-sdk.js'], function (Pi) {
  Pi.init({ version: '2.0' });

  // Authenticate the user and request payments
  const scopes = ['payments'];
  function onIncompletePaymentFound(payment) { /* ... */ }
  Pi.authenticate(scopes, onIncompletePaymentFound)
    .then(function (auth) {
      console.log(`Hi there! You're ready to make payments!`);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
"""
            ]);
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
The following LegacyJavaScriptObject object was thrown while handling a gesture:
  Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function() { return CanvasKitInit; }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
require.js 168:17                                                                                                              makeError
require.js 1254:36                                                                                                             intakeDefines
require.js 1446:21                                                                                                             localRequire
require.js 1797:24                                                                                                             requirejs
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/js_patch.dart 144:53                  eval
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/js_patch.dart 144:53                  callMethod
packages/remenberit/test.dart 20:24                                                                                            <fn>
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1096:21                                                                            handleTap
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 253:24                                                                           invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 627:11                                                                                  handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 306:5                                                                                   [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 239:7                                                                                   handlePrimaryPointer
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 615:9                                                                            handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:12                                                                        [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                                                                        <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13          forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                                                                       [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                                                                        route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 460:19                                                                              handleEvent
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution for this ??